# Why doesn't the “ls -1” command work correctly?

Tags: linux, command-line, ls

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6SWLv.jpg]

I'm trying to learn linux commands, but the output wasn’t what I expected.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`ls -1` (one) and `ls -l` (ell) both work, but produce different listings.  Your textbook shows `ls -l`; in your terminal you have typed `ls -1`.

[`man ls`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ls) on your local system for an explanation of all the available options.